# GLSL Per Pixel Point Lighting Issue

Tags: c++, glsl, pixel, vertex, lighting

I want to use a point light calculated in GLSL. I works fine, but if I calculate it per pixel it still looks the same as the Vertex based calculation.

My Vertex Code:

```
uniform vec3 LightPos;
varying vec2 UVCoord;
varying vec3 Normal;
varying vec3 posToLight;

void main()
{           
    UVCoord = gl_MultiTexCoord0.st;
    gl_Position = ftransform();
    Normal = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal);

    vec3 pos = vec3(gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex);
    posToLight = normalize(LightPos - pos);
}
```

My Fragment Code:

```
uniform sampler2D tex1;
varying vec2 UVCoord;
varying vec3 Normal;
varying vec3 posToLight;

void main()
{
    vec3 Color = vec3(texture2D(tex1, UVCoord));
    float LightIntensity = pow(max(dot(posToLight, Normal), 0.0), 10.0);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(Color * (LightIntensity), 1.0);
}
```

Does anybody have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: first of all, you have sent vertex shader instead of fragment shader :)

Comment: That is not point lighting; it's directional. Even so, the pow should  yield an easily visible difference even though you should consider normalizing the normal in the fragment shader.